# Execute `pipenv` commands from within python script

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I am trying to automate setup of a bunch of Python repos:

```
    repo = Repo(repository_path)

    # switch to `master` branch
    try:
        repo.git.checkout("master")
    except GitError:
        logger.error("Branch `master` does not exist.")
        return

    # if virtual environment directory does not exist run pipenv install command
    if not repository_path.joinpath(".venv").exists():
        os.chdir(repository_path)
        subprocess.call("pipenv install")
```

I am executing this from another venv and it seems that packages are installed inside current venv.

In fact I need to call `pipenv update` to update `Pipfile.lock` on bunch of repos but there are cases when venv is not set up at all.

Any hint how to run pipenv from within python script without interfering current venv ?